# Get & Edit a data in one request in PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql

I want to edit a column data into my Sql database without make two requests:

**For example:**

```
$var = "cde";
```

**First Request give me:**

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField='1'
$myVar = "abc";
```

**I want to update $var1 into my sql table to have:**

```
UPDATE myTable SET `myField`='$myVar'.'$var' WHERE myField='1'
```

Actually, I need to make two request.
One to have the first data, the second to update with my new value.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your table structure. Where `$var` and `$var1` values come from? Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), or [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to set the variable in a single query

Something like this

**With concat**

```
$addThis = 'cde';
$sql = "update mytable set mycolumn = concat(mycolumn, ', $addThis') where myconditions";
//execute query here
```

**With concat_ws**

```
$sql = "update mytable set mycolumn = concat_ws(', ', mycolumn, '$addThis') where myconditions.
```